# Using Netty inside JBoss 7 AS

Tags: java, sockets, netty, jboss7.x

I want to implement simple socket client using `ChannelPipelineFactory` inside JBoss 7.0.2 AS.

So I added `org.jboss.netty module` in `standalone.xml` file but deploying my war file causes `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelPipelineFactory` exception!

How can I make Netty library available for my war file?

My another question is may I use JMS for TCP/IP socket communication inside JBoss Application Server ?

Comment: There's a good chance JBoss 7 already contains Netty as one its own libraries. Have you looked in the included JAR files?

Comment: JBoss Contains Netty but I can't figure out how to use it in my own web app!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found the solution, based on http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-AS7FAQ I only needed to add Netty dependency to  'MANIFEST.MF' in 'META-INF' folder of my war file as:
dependencies: org.jboss.netty

Answer (score 1):

You can find some Netty library  in JBoss, in the `modules/org/jboss/netty/main` directory. But I have no idea how it works inside JBoss.

Comment: Yes the Netty library is there and as I said I tried to enable it by adding it to modules in JBoss configuration file but it didn't work.